# ipnat.conf rdr won't work solaris 10

Tags: oracle, redirection

I'm currently trying to achieve the following from the ipnat.conf configuration file on solaris 10:
I need my server to act like proxy between two specific hosts (with specific ports).

Lets say hostA need to send some data to my server in port 1111 tcp and then i need my server to send this data to hostB in port 2222 tcp, and of course I need that this will act to both direction to achive the "TCP" functionality.

I tried with rdr but I cant understand if the redirction is taking place ( but for sure can't get any tcp protocols to work).
I have checked the manual page in freeBSD site and oracle docs.. still no clue how to do it right.
First time on oracle machine.